# How do you handle data in which no observations exist for a given combination?

Tags: regression, logistic, modeling

I often run into a problem where I want to run a regression so that I can adjust for possible confounders. However, sometimes I have a very good relationship, actually too good of a relationship in a binary predictor, in which none exists for a given outcome and thus the regression refuses to run.

Does anyone know how to predict on such data or is it impossible? Am I reduced to having to run classical tests of hypotheses such as chi-squared for such data, and therefore unable to adjust for confounders?

Example data:

```
clear
input byte(AGEatpresentation SEX SURGYESNO ENDOTREATYESNO COMPLETEOBLITERATIONYESNO)
48 1 0 1 1
66 2 0 1 0
59 1 0 1 0
23 2 0 1 1
49 2 1 0 1
65 2 0 1 1
59 2 0 1 0
43 1 1 1 1
34 2 0 1 0
22 2 1 1 1
27 1 0 1 1
51 1 1 0 1
38 2 0 1 0
44 1 0 1 1
46 2 1 0 1
24 2 0 1 1
56 1 0 1 0
10 2 1 1 1
36 1 0 1 1
45 2 0 1 0
66 2 0 1 1
37 2 0 1 1
63 2 0 1 1
58 2 0 1 1
29 2 1 1 1
21 2 1 1 1
44 1 1 0 1
38 2 0 1 1
38 2 0 1 1
65 1 0 1 0
 5 2 0 1 1
28 2 0 1 0
55 1 0 1 1
39 2 0 1 0
46 2 1 0 1
61 1 0 1 0
50 1 1 1 1
56 1 1 1 1
50 2 0 1 0
31 1 0 1 1
53 1 0 1 0
25 1 1 1 1
18 2 0 1 1
70 1 1 1 1
10 2 0 1 1
57 1 0 1 1
67 1 0 1 1
41 2 0 1 0
26 2 0 1 0
68 2 1 0 1
59 2 0 1 1
43 1 0 1 1
43 1 0 1 1
33 2 0 1 1
53 2 0 1 0
24 2 0 1 1
53 2 0 1 1
16 2 0 1 1
61 2 0 1 1
46 2 1 1 1
67 1 0 1 0
31 2 1 1 1
45 1 0 1 1
26 1 1 0 1
 8 2 0 1 1
59 2 0 1 1
57 1 0 1 1
36 1 0 1 1
57 2 0 1 0
40 1 0 1 0
66 1 0 1 0
15 2 1 0 1
46 2 1 0 1
65 1 0 1 0
 9 1 0 1 0
28 1 0 1 0
18 1 0 1 1
55 2 1 1 1
37 1 0 1 1
50 1 0 1 0
31 2 1 0 1
41 1 0 1 0
43 1 1 1 1
75 2 0 1 1
40 1 1 1 1
39 1 0 1 1
71 1 0 1 0
49 2 0 1 1
17 2 1 1 1
41 1 0 1 0
32 2 0 1 0
47 1 0 1 1
26 2 0 1 1
22 1 1 1 1
20 1 0 1 0
11 2 0 1 1
42 2 1 1 1
53 2 1 0 1
35 2 0 1 0
54 2 0 1 1
end
```

Problem happens when trying to regress with `COMPLETEOBLITERATIONYESNO` as outcome for `SURGYESNO` adjusting for `SEX` and `AGEatpresentation`. Same happens when trying to run the same analysis for `ENDOTREATYESNO`. Due to missing data for a combination of these.